# What has to occur for Quickhit Braces' damage to be maximized?

Tags: dnd-4e, multiattack

[Quickhit braces](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/item.aspx?id=2627):

Property: When using a power, if you hit one creature with both your main weapon and your off-hand weapon, deal an extra 2d6 damage to that creature.

If I'm using twin-strike, when is the damage applied, and is it ever maximized due to crit?

Comment: Good question. I'd say no because the extra damage is not tied to a specific attack but to a combination of two (what if you crit with your main attack and not with the second?) But I am really unsure about it.

Comment: Missed the 1st part of the question. I think the damage is applied as soon as the conditions met, that is: when you have hit twice (independently by which weapon connected last).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there are two possible readings of this - the one that I would support, as it does not introduce any weird contradictions, and does not feel grossly overpowered:

**When is the extra damage applied?** Once you have resolved both the main hand weapon attack and the offhand weapon attack.

**Is the damage ever maximized due to a crit?** No.

And the one that I would not, based on reading an awful lot into the word extra:

**When is the extra damage applied?** As bonus damage dice to *each* of the attacks.

**Is the damage ever maximized due to a crit?** Yes, probably, as they appear to be bonus damage dice.

But then for powers that allow for main and off hand attacks, but have one triggering on a hit from the other, do you apply retroactive damage?