# Does Assassins Strike deal Max damage on a Critical hit?

Tags: dnd-4e, critical-hit

My friends and I are debating whether the Assasin's Strike power is maxxed on a crit roll.  Since it is not declared until after the hit we weren't sure on the ruling.

As I understand it it is either:

A) Considered extra damage (since it is not always in play) and therefore rolled above the normal Maxxed Attack.

B) Maxxed along with the rest of the damage since it is not a weapon, implement or High Crit. (as it says on the Players Handbook).  It is a power and as such added on as max damage to the rest of the role.

I've read similar questions in the forums but nothing directly related to Assasin's Strike.

Comment: Duplicate of http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/9340/12011

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

Even stuff you declare *after* a hit is maxed on a crit. The *only* thing that isn't is something that specifically happens *because* of the crit.

So if you have a hit that's eligible for Assassin's strike (or sneak attack, or anything else that is optionally declared *after* a hit) it's maxed.